# How to force shipping calculation in cart page?

Tags: shipping

I want to show the shipping amount on the shopping cart page. Currently Magento calculates shipping only on the checkout page. As a result when the user lands on the shopping cart page, he is not able to see the shipping amount.

How do I force Magento to calculate shipping on the shopping cart page itself?

Answer (score 1):

Shipping calculation in cart page is possible out-the-box.
It is most likely your theme has removed the display of shipping in cart.

[image]

Look for a line like this:

```
    <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping" />
```

in your xml layout (possible local.xml), and remove it.

Comment: I think my requirement will be met by writing a custom shipping module.

Comment: ProxiBlue is correct, shipping estimates on cart page come out of box.  Perhaps do a design swap back to base/default in admin > system > design to compare.  Custom shipping module shouldn't be required.